# gRPC C++ grpc::Status::error_message does not report failure reason

Tags: grpc, grpc-c++

I am implementing a gRPC C++ client with both TCP and TLS support.
My server is a simulator written in Go.

My problem is that in all the following cases, the error message is the same and that it is very generic, not indicating the failure reason:
More specific, the error message I get is in all the following cases:
"**failed to connect to all addresses**"
Cases:
A. Server is down during connection attempt
B. Client is TLS and server is TCP. Both are up and running
C. Client is TCP and server is TLS. Both are up and running
D. Client and server are TLS, but there is certificate mismatch. Both are up and running

Because I am working on a customer project, the customer should know what is the reason the connection attempt has failed. It is not acceptable to just report in the relevant alarm that "**failed to connect to all addresses**"

Of course there is a log in "ssl_transport_security", but this cannot be used by the program. I would assume that the grpc::Status object would be more accurate.

Any way that the client process gets in a std::string the failure reason, so that I can report it to the customer?
If there is a way, could you provide a code -snippet? Do the error_details provide such info? Code snippet?

Thanks!

My code snippet:

```
//Channel creation
bool isTls = true;
grpc::SslCredentialsOptions ssl_opts;
ssl_opts.pem_root_certs = ReadFile("ca.crt");
ssl_opts.pem_cert_chain = ReadFile("client.crt");
ssl_opts.pem_private_key = ReadFile("client.key");
if (ssl_opts.pem_root_certs.empty() || ssl_opts.pem_cert_chain.empty() || ssl_opts.pem_private_key.empty()) {
    isTls = false;
}
auto channelArgs = grpc::ChannelArguments();
channelArgs.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_INITIAL_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS, 2000);
channelArgs.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_MIN_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS, 2000);
channelArgs.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_MAX_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS, 2000);
if (isTls) {
    m_channel = grpc::CreateCustomChannel(url, grpc::SslCredentials(ssl_opts), channelArgs);
} else {
    m_channel = grpc::CreateCustomChannel(url, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials(), channelArgs);
}

//on_response callback implementation for rpc "rpc Send(stream gnmi.SubscribeResponse) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);"
void on_response(const grpc::Status &status, const google::protobuf::Empty *response)
{
    cout << "on_response code: " << status.error_code() << ", message: " << status.error_message() << "\n";
}
```

Output:
on_response code: 14 , message: failed to connect to all addresses

Expecting:
More accurate message, indicating the failure reason, e.g. connection refused, certificate mismatch, e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

you are not using TLS - SslCredentialsOptions is for older SSL versions. your handshake will fails - you can see that by turning tracing on: GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug GRPC_TRACE=tcp,http,api ./your binary